# Is there a way to declare a class then initialize it in a function in c++?

Tags: c++, class, initialization

I would like to know if there was a way to declare a class before a function, and then initialize it inside of a function, something like this:

Application.h:

```
class Application
{
  Application(HWND hwnd);
  ~Application() {}
};
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include "Application.h"
#include <Windows.h>

Application App;

int main()
{
  App(hwnd);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the real problem you want to solve? The object is initialized during construction, what would the object be before the constructor is called?

Comment: You're not declaring a class, you're declaring an *instance*, and yes, dynamic allocation is one such way. Now, *why* do you ask?

Comment: I'd declare `App` as a pointer and dynamically allocate it in your function. AFAIK there's no way to do this statically.

Comment: @WhozCraig I need to declare it before the function because I use the class functions within two functions. winMain() and MsgProc().

Answer (score 1):

```
Application *pApp;

int main()
{
  pApp = new Application(hwnd);

  //use pApp

  delete pApp;
  return 0;
}
```

Using a pointer is pretty much the only way to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot initialize a global object inside a function, the constructor of the object will be called some time before the main function of the program is called. This is very bad, it involves the thing called static initialization fiasco and you want to avoid it. Try to search for singleton pattern implementation in C++, that's what you need probably.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ the constructor for an object is called when the storage for it is allocated, you cannot call the constructor later like you tried to do.

You might consider not defining a constructor, and using a separate member function, for example `init`, to initialize your App object.

Application.h:

```
class Application
{
public:
    void init(HWND hwnd);
};
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include "Application.h"
#include <Windows.h>

Application App;

int main()
{
    App.init(hwnd);
    return 0;
}
```